# WCF service as stateless service in Service fabric

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, azure-service-fabric

I am creating SOAP service (ASMX service) into WCF service with BasicHttpBinding. Same as implemented [here](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.WcfCalc)

Wrote Interface as follows

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IExample
    {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebMethod]
    Task<XmlElement> GetDetails ();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "Get", UriTemplate = "/GetExample")]
    Task<string> GetExample (string guid);
    }
```

Implementations of Interface:

```
        public class ImplementInteface: IExample{
        public ImplementInterface(){}

        public Task<XmleElement> GetDetails(){
            //Implementation of GetDetails function
        }

        public Task<string> GetExample(string guid){
            //Implementation of GetExampl function
        }
    }
```

After running service fabric, stateless service running properly.

I have legacy code(asmx file) where same structure was already defined and having ATPs for the same. URL where the legacy apis are exposed, I don't want to mess it.
I want to expose new SOAP apis to the same URL.
But, when I try to call new SOAP APIs from stateless service, it is giving me **Bad request** as an error.
Is there any way to Create these apis into stateless service in service fabric?

Comment: Here's an example of a WCF service: https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.WcfCalc

Comment: _"...SOAP service (ASMX service) into WCF..."_ - well ASMX services aren't SOAP services nor do they use WCF.  ASMX services predate WCF and SOAP

Comment: @LoekD, I implemented my service by considering your code as a reference. Thanks for that.
But, when I try to run my ATPs to test perticular API, then those ATPs are failing, giving me bad request as a result. I am new to SOAP API.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work just like that.
**SOAP** entails enclosing client requests (actually their body) into an XML.

Typing the address into the browser won't create any XML, but send a plain request

So,

1. Either you use something else to send a SOAP request (e.g. a **WCF client**, that you must write in C#, or a third-party product like **SoapUI**)
2. Or you give up the SOAP requirement and use WCF to create a **REST** service, which won't require an XML body and can be called via browser

If you decide to go with #2, you must add this attribute in your svc file

```
Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"
```